Can you remove the 'Default' column on storybook controls addon?

I can't seem to find in the documentation anywhere about this Default column, and I would like to remove it from my storybook because it's not doing anything.
I would prefer to do this on a global level instead of an individual story level if possible.

You can do a workaround
.docblock-argstable .docblock-argstable-head th:nth-child(3) {
  display: none !important;
}


.docblock-argstable .docblock-argstable-body td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none !important;
}

But you need to link the stylesheet to manager-head.html inside .storybook dir
